# android application login with Zend Framework

Tags: android, zend-framework, authentication

> I am developing an application in which I have to create login and registration activity and get response from the back-end. My back-end team is using ZEND FRAMEWORK for creating website from which I have to get response. Please tell me how to check credentials and get response from Zend?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpClient library to send requests to the website your backend team are building:

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html

From your perspective it does not matter what framework or language they have used, you will be performing regular HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

You Could use some Libraries to consume WebServices, 
i recommend :

- [Volley By Android](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)
- [Retrofit by Square](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

In my opinion both are good, in my case I use Volley, it is fast, extensible, and it does not run in MainThread.

Regards.

Comment: when I am sending request to php backend, it gives me proper response. but when I try to hit Zend backend, It gives error in Login method and this line..."Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());"